# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания? (2)

Tags: пунктуация

В.Попков-изобразил один из осенних дней Александра Сергеевича Пушкина. На картине изображено, как был ветреный и дождливый день. Александр Сергеевич стоял на крыльце своего дома, и просто смотрел на то, как деревья шелестели и раскачивались от ветра. Это было действительно красиво! Спускаясь по ступенькам крыльца, можно увидеть лавочку, на которой Александр Сергеевич любил проводить своё свободное время.
Смотря вдаль, можно увидеть большое, золотисто-зелёное поле, на котором иногда можно увидеть лошадей. Порывы ветра вызывали большой шелест деревьев, который слушал Александр Сергеевич. Ветер развивал его сюртук, но Александр Сергеевич этого не замечал.
Смотря на картину, можно увидеть, что художник передал всю красочность и душевность своего вдохновения.

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Comment: Ветер развивал его сюртук - гениально.

Comment: Вы хоть знаете что такое сюртук?

Comment: Если вы не знали,то я в 8 классе,и я наверное лучше знаю какое сочинение подходит  лучше!И я попросила помочь проверить,а не критиковать!

Comment: "На картине изображено,как был ветреный и дождливый день" неплохо.. Знаки вроде верные. Только точек с запятыми не хватает на концах строк, а то не похоже на алгоритм..

Comment: Даша, а Вы знаете, что значит "развивать"? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Dasha, я бы переделал здесь многое, но вопрос был только о знаках препинания, поэтому я проверил только их, да еще исправил явную ошибку (о развитии сюртука).

*В.Попков [тире не нужно] изобразил один из осенних дней Александра Сергеевича Пушкина. На картине изображено, как был ветреный и дождливый день. Александр Сергеевич стоял на крыльце своего дома [запятая не нужна] и просто смотрел на то, как деревья шелестели и раскачивались от ветра. Это было действительно красиво! Спускаясь по ступенькам крыльца, можно увидеть лавочку, на которой Александр Сергеевич любил проводить своё свободное время.
Смотря вдаль, можно увидеть большое, золотисто-зелёное поле, на котором иногда можно увидеть лошадей. Порывы ветра вызывали большой шелест деревьев, который слушал Александр Сергеевич. Ветер развевал [развивал - ошибка] его сюртук, но Александр Сергеевич этого не замечал.
Смотря на картину, можно увидеть, что художник передал всю красочность и душевность своего вдохновения.*